# Bootstrap code is not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML isn't linking to the Bootstrap CSS. I've downloaded bootstrap and copied the CSS, FONTS, and JS folders to a folder 'called bootstrap' on my desktop. I created and index.html file in the same folder containing the CSS, FONTS, and JS. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstap.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="well">Something goes here</form>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use 'inspect element' the JS and CSS files show up with the full correct file path `.../desktop/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css`.

I'm at a loss as to what is going on.

Comment: `bootstrap.js` need jQuery installed. Try view source on your browser and click that `css/bootstrap.css` if it's pointing to the right file.

Comment: may be bootstrap.css meaning mistake

Answer (score 0):

You spelt bootstrap wrong.

> css/bootstap.css